# Bash script to generate multiple files with fixed size

Tags: bash, file, size, fixed

I need a simple bash script or a line to generate a number of files with a fixed size, I need to be able to choose the site and the number either in the file or by input.

I tried solutions I found online, but they are either about creating multiple files, or about creating a single file with fixed size, not both things together.

For example:

```
for i in {1..5}; do dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1024 count=50 of=test.bin
```

This still creates only a single file though, not multuple.

Comment: `;` <- this one makes empty iteration. You don't create file in loop, you create it after loop ends.

Comment: `touch file{1..5} && truncate -s 50K file{1..5}`?

Answer (score 0):

As [Tom K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2703276/tom-k) pointed there is a problem with your for loop.
It should be something like

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in 1 2 3 4 5
do
   dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1024 count=50 of=test-${i}.bin
done
```

resulting:

```
ll test-*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 50K Aug 20 23:48 test-1.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 50K Aug 20 23:48 test-2.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 50K Aug 20 23:48 test-3.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 50K Aug 20 23:48 test-4.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 50K Aug 20 23:48 test-5.bin
```

Edit.
Or onliner if you prefer:

```
for i in {1..5}; do dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1024 count=50 of=test-${i}.bin; done
```